# NPM crashes when I try to update a package with --depth 21

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, npm-update

I'm trying to fix the npm vulnerabilities in my project. On trying `npm audit` I got a command to fix the vulnerability in one of the packages.

`$ npm update kind-of --depth 21`

On running this command, I'm getting the following message:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->
[27677:0x43e27b0]   655989 ms: Mark-sweep 1092.0 (1432.7) -> 1092.0 (1425.7) MB, 1401.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.031, current mu = 0.007) last resort GC in old space requested
[27677:0x43e27b0]   657562 ms: Mark-sweep 1092.0 (1425.7) -> 1092.0 (1425.7) MB, 1573.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.016, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested
<--- JS stacktrace --->
==== JS stack trace =========================================
    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x6d8f26dbe1d]
Security context: 0x3d028b51e6e1 <JSObject>
    1: isExtraneous(aka isExtraneous) [0x21dd9bc867d1] [/home/qburst/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/is-extraneous.js:~4] [pc=0x6d8f2f64036](this=0x36cf643826f1 <undefined>,tree=0x0ca9a56e2291 <Node map = 0x391751aadd89>)
    2: /* anonymous */ [0x219a048fa6f9] [/home/qburst/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/out...
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x8daaa0 node::Abort() [npm]
 2: 0x8daaec  [npm]
 3: 0xad73ce v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [npm]
 4: 0xad7604 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [npm]
 5: 0xec4c32  [npm]
 6: 0xed444f v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [npm]
 7: 0xea21e8 v8::internal::Factory::NewTransitionArray(int, int) [npm]
 8: 0x11db913 v8::internal::TransitionsAccessor::Insert(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::SimpleTransitionFlag) [npm]
 9: 0xfcb9b6 v8::internal::Map::ConnectTransition(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::SimpleTransitionFlag) [npm]
10: 0x1005d26 v8::internal::Map::CopyReplaceDescriptors(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::DescriptorArray>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::LayoutDescriptor>, v8::internal::TransitionFlag, v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Name>, char const*, v8::internal::SimpleTransitionFlag) [npm]
11: 0x1007764 v8::internal::Map::CopyAddDescriptor(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::Descriptor*, v8::internal::TransitionFlag) [npm]
12: 0x1007943 v8::internal::Map::CopyWithField(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FieldType>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::PropertyConstness, v8::internal::Representation, v8::internal::TransitionFlag) [npm]
13: 0x100cc55 v8::internal::Map::TransitionToDataProperty(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::PropertyConstness, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) [npm]
14: 0xfb35b8 v8::internal::LookupIterator::PrepareTransitionToDataProperty(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSReceiver>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) [npm]
15: 0xff0109 v8::internal::Object::AddDataProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::PropertyAttributes, v8::internal::ShouldThrow, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) [npm]
16: 0x100ad7d v8::internal::Object::SetProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::LanguageMode, v8::internal::Object::StoreFromKeyed) [npm]
17: 0x11654d5 v8::internal::Runtime::SetObjectProperty(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::LanguageMode) [npm]
18: 0x1166630 v8::internal::Runtime_SetProperty(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [npm]
19: 0x6d8f26dbe1d 
[1]    27677 abort (core dumped)  npm update kind-of --depth 21
```

Could someone help me with this issue? Thank you.

Comment: What're the versions of node and npm?

Comment: @troy Please note:

node `v10.13.0`
npm  `6.4.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had encountered the same error and from looking at the error my intuition is that `npm update` at that depth of dependency tree is not feasible with our default resource settings of Node.js. (I confess that I have not researched more on this)

Assuming I am close to truth in my above deduction, I do not recommend increasing any such default resource limits unless we know for sure what values are safe and good. Also because this issue happened only for a corner case while using `npm`.

I see that you were trying to forcefully update [kind-of](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kind-of) at a certain level of dependency tree by running:

```sh
npm update kind-of --depth 21
```

However, since [kind-of](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kind-of) is a very widely used package, I suggest that you check all other levels of dependency tree (`npm ls kind-of`) and make sure if fixing [kind-of](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kind-of)'s version only at `depth 21` will make your `npm audit` clean.

## Solution (workaround)

Use [npm-force-resolutions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions). Quoting from the package's description:

> This packages modifies `package-lock.json` to force the installation of
>   specific version of a transitive dependency (dependency of
>   dependency), similar to [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/)'s selective dependency resolutions, but
>   without having to migrate to [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/).

Before you use it, let me also warn you

> The use case for this is when there is a security vulnerability and
>   you MUST update a nested dependency otherwise your project would be
>   vulnerable. But this should only be used as a last resource, you
>   should first update your top-level dependencies and file an issue for
>   them to update the vulnerable sub-dependencies (`npm ls`  can help you with that).

In your `package.json`, you just need to add a `preinstall` script

```
"scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
}
```

and a directive field

```js
"resolutions": {
    "kind-of": ">=6.0.3"
}
```

(assuming you want to fix [kind-of](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kind-of) version to get rid of [CVE-2019-20149](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2019-20149))